# Spark Streaming Save to HBase Conditionally

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

What i was trying to do is, integrate Kafka to Spark streaming and check the counts of words. If a word count reaches to a threshold, let say 5, save it to HBase with word, count. The problem is that when the threshold reaches it resends the data into HBase again and again with the window size(2 seconds).

I store the variables with the form of PairRDD such that (String, (Long, String)), which is (Word, (Count, Send/Sent/NoOp)). If a word count is reached to the threshold, it changes x._2._2 to Send and another map operation is done to save the "Send" signed words to HBase and converts them into "Sent".

My code is like this:

```
def reduceFunc(x: (Long,String), y: (Long,String)): (Long, String) = {
    var result: (Long, String) = null
    var op = "nop"
    var count = x._1+y._1
    if (x._1<=5 && count>5 ) {
      op = "send"
    }
    result = (count, op)
    result
  }
.
.
.
var wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, (1L, "nop")))
      .reduceByKeyAndWindow(reduceFunc, reduceFunc_inv, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
//Filter only send states
var toAlert = wordCounts.filter(x => x._2._2 == "send")
// For each word to send, save into HBase
toAlert.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
              val now = Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis
              val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
              hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", quorum)
              HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(hbaseConf)
              val tableName = "test"
              val table = new HTable(hbaseConf, tableName)

              val resultRdd = rdd.map { tuple =>  (tuple._1.asInstanceOf[String].getBytes(), 
                        scala.collection.immutable.Map( columnFamily -> 
                                Array( ( columnName, (tuple._2._1.toString, now) ) ) 
                        ) 
                  )
              }
              sendToHBase(resultRdd, hbaseConf, tableName)
}
//Save operation is done. Therefore, change the send states to sent.
wordCounts = wordCounts.map{ x => 
    if (x._2._2 == "send")
      (x._1, (x._2._1,"sent"))
    else
      x
 }
```

It works and saves the word that exceeds the thresholds into HBase. However, when a word reaches 6 it updates the HBase table for each 2 seconds. Once the word reaches 7 it gives up to resend it.

I don't know what i miss in the context. I also tried updateStateByKey and found it very slow and can miss some inputs. If i send too many words very fast, it counts them one. Maybe there is another way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

If you need my installation is with Cloudera CDH 5.9.0 with 12 nodes. Spark version is 1.6.0 and HBase is 1.2.0.

Comment: Really? Noone cares about hadoop and spark world?